# jQuery, break or reset after click event

Tags: jquery, html

I may be going about this wrong, but I am trying to have jQuery tell an HTML element to do xyz on click.  I am able to get xyz to work, but I would like the functions to restart after a new click has been initiated.

In this example, I am have a main image, which has thumbnails.  When a thumb nail is clicked, the featured image changes and has some effect.  The problem is with my current code, when you click multiple thumbnails, it adds the click event to a que to be processed in order.

```
$("div.thumb").click(function() {
    var primary_image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('div.main-image').effect( "blind", {direction: "left" }, 500, function() {
        $('div.main-image').html('<img src="' + primary_image + '"/>');
    });
    $('div.main-image').show( "blind", {direction: "left" }, 200 );
});
```

What is the ideal way to accomplish this?

---

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7613t1pp/)**

---

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle I will help you out

Comment: Are you looking for jQuery's `.stop()` function?

Comment: You are using jquery UI right? https://api.jqueryui.com/effect/ add queue: false

Comment: add your **HTML** please

Comment: I have included a JS fiddle that outlines the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thumb").click(function() {
    var primary_image = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.main-image').effect({
      effect: "blind",
      direction: "left",
      duration: 500,
      queue: false,
      complete: function() {
        $('.main-image').html('<img src="' + primary_image + '"/>').show("blind", {
          direction: "left"
        }, 500);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.main-image {
  text-align: center;
}

.thumb-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.thumb {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="thumb-wrapper">
  <div class="thumb" rel="//i.imgur.com/V8EUWYl.jpg">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/b9l2d48.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumb" rel="https://i.imgur.com/BDyucxj.jpg">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/1eLKcFX.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumb" rel="//i.imgur.com/17b7xgx.jpg">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/OniG5jY.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumb" rel="//i.imgur.com/6YEazO3.jpg">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/A8aVtpx.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-image"><img src="//i.imgur.com/V8EUWYl.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation, the queue parameter is set to true by default. Setting it to false should solve the issue

Note that I am passing the animation options as an object

```
$("div.thumb").click(function() {
    var primary_image = $(this).attr("rel");

    $('div.main-image').effect({
        effect : "blind",
        direction: "left",
        duration: 500,
        complete: function() {
            $('div.main-image').html('<img src="' + primary_image + '"/>');
        },
        queue: false
    });
    $('div.main-image').show( "blind", {direction: "left" }, 200 );
});
```

Comment: This was helpful, I will upvote when I earn enough points.  Cheers

Comment: @CleanCode did my solution not work? It looks the other solution is a copy of mine which is posted 53 mins later than mine

Comment: There may have been a caching issue on my end as I did not see your answer until I came back the third time to this question to review the replies.  --- Your solution did work, but I referenced the following url to make my decision: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers

Comment: @CleanCode not that I care for who you mark correct because that your right, but the other answer doesn't even have any explanation and it came in way later